# WOL remote Windows pc's at startup

Tags: windows, script, wake-on-lan

I have five Windows 8.1 pc's all connected together to the same local network.
I'd like to automatically switch on my 4 slaves when I power on my Master pc.

All the machines are properly set up to use Wake On LAN features and I was able to turn them on individually using the PowerOn.exe I found here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11469/Wake-On-LAN-WOL

Unfortunately this is not good enough because I want my Master pc to run a script at startup and wake up all the other pc's. I didn't find any suitable script on the internet and I would be glad if someone could show me the correct way to achieve this goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some WOL softwares have a command line feature, like this one: http://www.depicus.com/wake-on-lan/wake-on-lan-cmd.aspx
Then you'll just need to write a batch file that launch a command and make this batch run on startup.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished using a [PowerShell script](http://blogs.technet.com/b/matthts/archive/2012/06/02/wakeup-machines-a-powershell-script-for-wake-on-lan.aspx).  It utilizes a CSV file to list the names of the machines to start.  Make sure to use version 1.1 of the script.